# How to get list of all JPMS layers?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I want to get all layers that are available now in JVM. However, via ModuleLayer I can get only empty and boot layers. It is possible to get all layers, for example even those, that are children of boot layer?

Comment: As far as I know you can get the parents of a `ModuleLayer` (and `Configuration`) but you can't get the children.

Comment: Well, you might just keep on iterating while finding the `parents` from your current ModuleLayer, unless you find the *boot layer*[(that is created when the Java virtual machine is started)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html) and that is when you can consider the traversal complete.

Comment: @nullpointer That works so long as you can guarantee every `ModuleLayer` is reachable, by only going towards the root, from the current `ModuleLayer`. If the graph gets complicated you may not be able to guarantee that. If the current `ModuleLayer` has a sibling, for instance, you won't be able to reach the sibling.

Comment: There is no support for discovering all the module layers in the heap. I think it would be useful to understand where this question is coming from? Is this for monitoring and management purposes?

Comment: @AlanBateman Yes, for monitoring and management. Could you say, if such feature would be available in the future?

Comment: @AlanBateman Besides this feature will be very useful for debuggin as in future (I hope) layers will be used for application extensions (plugins etc).

Comment: As @AlanBateman pointed out, you can currently only follow parent ModuleLayer links, not child links. I would have found it useful to be able to discover and scan all modules in the heap for ClassGraph, but realistically this is not useful to most users, because usually there's no point returning scan results that include classes and resources that are not visible to the caller code due to encapsulation. The exception to this is the case of manually-created/dynamic ModuleLayers that are not in the running code's own ModuleLayer graph. I allow these to be scanned, given a ModuleLayer reference.

Comment: I agree with @Pavel_K though that for debugging purposes, it would be very useful to be able to display the entire ModuleLayer graph, and the modules within each layer, whether or not the layers are actually visible to the calling code.